# Creating JTable java

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtable

I'm trying to read an XML file from a URL and then create a JTable with the data.

When I try just to print the data it works perfectly but something with the creation of the JTable is not working and I'm not sure why.

I dont get any exceptions or errors.

Here is the code i wrote, hope you can help me.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;   
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;



public class Table extends JTable {
JTable currTable; 
Object rowData[][] = new String[15][6];
Object columnNames[] = { "Name", "Unit", "CurrencyCode", "Country", "Rate", "Change" };

public Table() {

    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml"); 

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("CURRENCY");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                rowData[temp][0] = new String(eElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("NAME").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());
                rowData[temp][1] = new String(eElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("UNIT").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());
                rowData[temp][2] = new String(eElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("CURRENCYCODE").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());
                rowData[temp][3] = new String(eElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("COUNTRY").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());
                rowData[temp][4] = new String(eElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("RATE").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());
                rowData[temp][5] = new String(eElement
                        .getElementsByTagName("CHANGE").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    currTable = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame printTable = new JFrame("Exchange Rate Table");
    printTable.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JTable myTable = new Table();

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myTable);
    printTable.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    printTable.setSize(400, 500);
    printTable.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: `public class Table extends JTable {`  What the ..what?  First thing, don't extend table unless there is a clear case for doing so.

Comment: Oh, and see [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are adding the Table object, which extends `JTable`, to the `JScrollPane`. You don't add anything to it, instead you set the data to the `currTable` member variable. To make it work, you should change the 2 respective lines in your `main` function to the following:

```
Table myTable = new Table();

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myTable.currTable);
```

But really, it makes no sense to extend `JTable` from your `Table` class. Create a method that creates and returns the `rowData` object, and create a `JTable` in your main function like this:

```
JTable myTable = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
```

Also some more comments in order to improve your code:

- No need to call the `String` constructor, you are creating extra objects. `rowData[temp][0] = eElement.getElementsByTagName("NAME").item(0).getTextContent();` will work just as fine
- Don't hard code numbers like 15 and 6 in your array creation code. 15 should be the number of XML elements, which you can get with `nList.getLength()`. 6 is the length of the `columnNames` array.
- Take a look at the [Google Java Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! i know my code have some problems like calling the String constructor or the fact i used numbers instead of getLength.. i did this in order to understand what was wrong.. anyway your answer was very helpful :) thanks